# A group of 60 second graders is to be randomly assigned to two classes of 30 each.......

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A group of 60 second graders is to be randomly assigned to two classes of 30 each. Five of the second graders, Marcelle, Sarah, Michelle, Katy, and Camerin, are close friends.

(a) What is the probability that they will all be in the same class?

**Note:** This question was answered before: [Probability that 4 friends will be in the same class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408224/probability-that-4-friends-will-be-in-the-same-class)

But I have some issues:

**1)** I don't see how that is the answer

**2)** What is wrong with the approach I was attempting?

**My attempt at a)**

So first I found the sample space which I felt was $$\Omega = \binom{60}{30}$$

Then with that being the case I asked the question of "given that the 5 friends need to be together, in how many ways can I get the other 25 students for their group?" I wanted to get some arrangement of the form:  $$(55)(54)....(32)(31)$$ But If I do that then I have assumed that the 5 kids are in a specific group, which is not the case. But multiplying by $2$ will also no work because the other group is to have 30 kids in it.......

How could I (if possible) reconcile my answer with the other one?

Comment: To obtain a capital Greek letter, capitalize the first letter in its name.  For instance, you can produce  $\Omega$ by typing \Omega when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the chairs in the two classes are numbered $1-30$ and $31-60$. When we assign the students to classes, the five friends end up with random numbered chairs. The question is then whether the random set of five chairs we come up with are either all $\le 30$ or all $>30$.

Now there are $\binom{60}{5}$ sets of five possible chairs the friends *could* end up with, and $\binom{30}{5}+\binom{30}{5}$ of those keep the friends together ...

Answer (score 2):

We could consider "the other kids" as follows. Think of the group that Marcelle is in. There are $\binom{59}{29}$ equally likely ways to choose her classmates.

Now let us count the *favourables*, the ways in which her four friends are in her group. We need to choose $25$ people from the remaining $55$. This can be done in $\binom{55}{25}$ ways.

Thus the required probability is $\frac{\binom{55}{25}}{\binom{59}{29}}$.

Comment: I had initially though of something along those lines, but I had thought sample space = $\binom{60}{30}$ and then the way to choose the other $25$ people for a group would've been $\binom{55}{25}$ But I was concerned that I had not broken the students up into the 2 groups. Also why $59$ instead of $60$?

Comment: There are $59$ people who are not Marcelle.

Comment: @dc3rd: Thank you for the accept. However, *structurally* the type of analysis made by Henning Makholm is in general more useful, so you may wish to reconsider.